# PowerShell hashtable to CSV

Tags: powershell, get-childitem

I'm using a hashmap to get some filename, md5 and path details - the problem is I don't think I want a hashmap because I'm not really looking for the key/value pair but rather a CSV which contains a column for name, fullname and md5 - what's the best way to accomplish this is powershell?

here's my current code which I suppose I could use but then I'd end up having to "replace" all the key= stuff that I don't want in my final CSV.

```
$MD5Hashes = @{}
Get-ChildItem "C:\Users\Tony\Pictures\My Pictures\2009\03" -Recurse -File |  ForEach-Object {
  $MD5Hashes.Add($_.Name, (Get-FileHash -Path $_.FullName -Algorithm MD5 | Select-Object -Property * -ExcludeProperty Algorithm ))
}
```

Isn't there a simple way to get-ChildItem and just comma separate and newline each name, fullname and md5?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Select-Object` to create an object with all the properties that you want like this:

```
Get-ChildItem "C:\Users\Tony\Pictures\My Pictures\2009\03" -Recurse -File | select-object name, fullname, @{Name = "MD5"; Expression = {(Get-FileHash $_.FullName -Algorithm MD5).Hash}}
```

You can then just export the objects into a csv file using `Export-CSV` :

```
Get-ChildItem "C:\Users\Tony\Pictures\My Pictures\2009\03" -Recurse -File | select-object name, fullname, @{Name = "MD5"; Expression = {(Get-FileHash $_.FullName -Algorithm MD5).Hash}} | export-csv FilesWithHashs.csv -NoTypeInformation
```